# Cannot resolve method 'registerListener(com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity, android.hardware.SensorManager, int)'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensormanager

couldn't find a good answer to that problem.

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

  mSensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, mSensorManager, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```

Cannot resolve method 'registerListener(com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity, android.hardware.SensorManager, int)'

and I have no idea what to do

Whole activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ImageView image, shield;
private float currentDegree = 0f;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private TextView tvHeading;
private Location location = new Location("A");
private Location target = new Location("B");
private LocationManager locationManager;
private EditText latitudeInput, longitudeInput;
public GeomagneticField geoField;
private Button setLocationBtn;
Dialog myDialog;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private  Sensor mAccelerometer;

private float[] floatGravity = new float[3];
private float[] floatGeoMagnetic = new float[3];

private float[] floatOrientation = new float[3];
private float[] floatRotationMatrix = new float[9];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.direction);
    shield = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shield);
    tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
    setLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    

    //location.setLatitude(54.903535);
    //location.setLongitude(23.979342);

    target.setLatitude(54.904618);
    target.setLongitude(23.978782);

    SensorEventListener sensorEventListenerAccelrometer = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            floatGravity = event.values;

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(floatRotationMatrix, null, floatGravity, floatGeoMagnetic);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(floatRotationMatrix, floatOrientation);
            mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            shield.setRotation((float) (-floatOrientation[0] * 180 / 3.14159));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   //mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this); // to stop the listener and save battery
}


//@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
    degree += geoField.getDeclination();

    float bearing = location.bearingTo(target);
    degree = (bearing - degree) * -1;
    degree = normalizeDegree(degree);

    tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    image.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree;
}

private float normalizeDegree(float value) {
    if (value >= 0.0f && value <= 180.0f) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return 180 + (180 + value);
    }
}


public void onSensorChanged2(SensorEvent event) {

    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

    tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    shield.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree;

}


public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // not in use
}


public void ShowPopup(View v) {
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    TextView txtclose;
    Button setBtn;

    txtclose =(TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    setBtn =(Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.setBtn);
    txtclose.setText("X");
    latitudeInput =(EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.latitudeInput);
    longitudeInput =(EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.longitudeInput);
    txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    setBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(latitudeInput == null || longitudeInput == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a coordinates", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else {
                target.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitudeInput.getText().toString()));
                target.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitudeInput.getText().toString()));
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();
}
```

My app should show the direction to a destination like a compass. The user will give a latitude and longitude.
Or maybe you have different ideas about how to make a compass to location

Comment: Where did you get this signature for ```registerListener```? There is no such signature according to the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев I used https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html code from this guy

Comment: Please, provide all code of this activity.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев ok I just added

Comment: Your activity should implement a specific interface like this: ```public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener```

Comment: @НиколайГольцев sorry for the obvious question but I'm a new developer how can I do that?

Comment: You should change this fragment of code ```public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity``` to this ```public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener```

Comment: @НиколайГольцев wow this work Man I Love you haha. now I have different error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.hardware.SensorManager.registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Try to debug your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem earlier dealing with the accelerometer. I believe the issue here is that you have not implemented `SensorEventListener`.

Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

}
```